# About tensorflow image retraining accuracy

Tags: tensorflow

In "tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/" [project](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining),

the **final test accuracy** is means "top-1 accuracy" or "top-5 accuracy" ?

Because I couldn't find this description in [this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining#training).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is is the top-1 accuracy. You can see by reading the code.

Comment: Thank you for your help.